# Flask-SQLAlchemy filter_by and follow multiple backrefs

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to extend the schema from the [Flask-SQLAlchemy Quickstart Simple Relationships example](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#simple-relationships) and add a class called `Editor`.

My schema now looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category',
        backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, title, body, category, pub_date=None):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        if pub_date is None:
            pub_date = datetime.utcnow()
        self.pub_date = pub_date
        self.category = category

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.title


class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

    editor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('editor.id'))
    editor = db.relationship('Editor',
        backref=db.backref('categories', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, name, editor):
        self.name = name
        self.editor = editor

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % self.name


class Editor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Editor %r>' % self.name
```

The queries from the example on the quickstart, in addition to the query for categories by editor, all work fine:

```
>>> py = Category('Python')
>>> p = Post('Hello Python!', 'Python is pretty cool', py)
>>> e = Editor('dude')
>>> db.session.add(py)
>>> db.session.add(p)
>>> db.session.add(e)
>>> Post.query.filter_by(category=py).all()
[<Post 'Hello Python!'>]
>>> Category.query.filter_by(editor=e).all()
[<Category 'Python'>]
```

However, I would also like to find all posts from a specific editor. I tried using this query:

```
>>> Post.query.filter_by(category.editor=e).all()
```

But I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

How do I get posts by editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the Post and Category first, and i made some small corrections on your tests:

```
db.create_all()
e = Editor('Dude')
py = Category('Python', e)
p = Post('Hello Python!', 'Python is pretty cool', py)
db.session.add(py)
db.session.add(p)
db.session.add(e)
print Post.query.filter_by(category=py).all()
print Category.query.filter_by(editor=e).all()
print Post.query.join(Category).filter_by(editor=e).all()
```